# UIAlertController dismiss is slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

After iOS 8, changing my implementation to UIAlertController instead of UIAlertView is giving me some headaches.

The dismissal takes around a full second before the UI becomes responsive after clicking a button. It means users think there's something wrong.

Am I the only one suffering from this? It's across several apps, and true for an implementation as simple as this. I tried this in a new blank project.

```
- (IBAction)showAlertView {

    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" message:@"test" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    NSLog(@"this is fast");
}

-(IBAction)showAlert {

    UIAlertController *controller = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"test" message:@"test" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [controller addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

        NSLog(@"this is slow");

    }]];

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];

}
```

Clicking the button gives around a 1-second delay before anything is printed to the console. Presentation of the alert is not delayed at all.

Edit: By closer timing it's probably more like 700ms, so not a full second, but still way too long for something that should be instantaneous.

Comment: Slow response from the UI is often caused by executing UI tasks on a background thread. Are you presenting this alert from an asynchronous completion handler?  There is certainly no general issue with UIAlertController.

Comment: This is just the code as is. Nothing is run on any explicit threads. I could bind above code to an IBAction and click a button to present the controller, it would still be slow. It's been like this every time I used it across all apps. I'm very confused.

Comment: It seems like it waits for a dismissal in much the same way it does when dismissing a view controller animated (cover vertical for instance). Without an animation on dismissal, you get much the same delay as I'm talking about here.

Comment: I just made `file->New project` then, copy/paste your code and bind it to a button: I do not have any delay. It's pretty smooth (on iPhone 6)
I think you have something working on another thread (or in the main thread).

Comment: Perhaps it's a question of what people consider slow, then. Can you try with the deprecated UIAlertView and compare them?

Comment: I just tried creating a new blank project with only above code bound to button. I still get the same 700ms-ish delay.

Comment: The alert dismisses equally fast, but the call to the handler is slightly slower in the case of UIAlertController. What issue is this causing?

Comment: Just unnecessary latency. It depends on how you use the alert, obviously, but in my case it gives a really poor user experience.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old question but I had the same problem and adding this in the ViewController presenting the UIAlertController solved it for me:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

Swift version:

```
override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Then there is something else that is wrong. Here is a clean project where the delay is gone after overriding canBecomeFirstResponder. 
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n56d44nozjecjzx/AlertControllerTest.zip?dl=0)

It contains swift and obj-c versions and it works on both iOS 8 and 9. You can experiment and change the return value to NO/false and you'll notice that the delay of 0.7sec is back.

Comment: Works for me. I wonder what's the underlying mechanism for this behavior.

Comment: I think this is how to do this in Swift 3.0:
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool { return true }
This didn't seem to change anything for me. Still a delay.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, overriding `canBecomeFirstResponder` did not help us.

What did help us was to call `resignFirstResponder` on any possible responders in the view controller BEFORE showing the alert.

For some reason, if a text field was a first responder, it looks like it would try to go through the view hierarchy looking for the next responder. If no text fields had any focus, the delay disappeared.

Comment: I know this is an old issue now, but I'm experiencing the same thing.. We are dropping support for iOS 7/8, and get deprecation warnings on `UIAlertView`. When converting to `UIAlertViewController` I observe that same delay of almost a second after clicking actions. The action-handler simply doesn't get called fast enough. We don't have any textfields or any object being firstResponder in this view, as far as I know.. Just like you couldn't have had in your question when you stated that this also happens in a completely fresh project (without any textviews)..